# .LYG file extension

Tags: file, file-extension

I am working on java project in which input is given from a file. The input file has extension .LYG how we can read the data of this file and for what purpose this extension is used. Is this a corrupted file? File contains following data:

`¬í sr java.util.Hashtable»%!Jä¸ F 
loadFactorI     thresholdxp?@     w   ¿   lt improvet Technology in Actiont team upt Contracts Centralt   introducet New Product Introductiont offshoret Outsourcing & Offshoringt reduceq ~ t sackingt Talent Trackert teams upq ~ t securest Tech Investt    offshoredq ~    t useq ~ t layoffq ~ t investedq ~ t joinst Executive Movest lawsuitt Intellectual Property Rightst raises $q ~ t appointq ~ t 
offshoringq ~   t   announcesq ~ t optimisationq ~ t innovateq ~ t partnerq ~ t researchingt R&Dt saveq ~ t investq ~ t unveilsq ~ t 
introducesq ~ t acquirest M&A Trackert 
getting readyq ~  t to buyq ~ &t nabsq ~ t trainingq ~ t ipq ~ t 
outsourcedq ~   t signsq ~ t captiveq ~  t 
introducedq ~ t    improvingq ~ t usesq ~ t patent lawsuitq ~ t releaseq ~ t puts $q ~ t researchq ~  t 
developingq ~  t partnersq ~ t 
steps downq ~ t    take overq ~ &t bands togetherq ~ t optimiseq ~ t developmentq ~  t lays offq ~ t    appointedq ~ t launchq ~ t   launchingq ~ t acquireq ~ &t 
partneringq ~ t developsq ~  t    brings inq ~ t     inks pactq ~ t patentq ~ t skill buildingq ~ t outsourcingq ~     t makesq ~ t reducingq ~ t raisesq ~ t buysq ~ &t signs upq ~ t joinq ~ t raised $q ~ t leaving the companyq ~ t pumps $q ~ t appointsq ~ t  step downq ~ t mergesq ~ &t left the companyq ~ t hiringq ~ t raisedq ~ t mergerq ~ &t r&dq ~  t strategic partnerq ~ t unveiledq ~ t skillq ~ t pumpsq ~ t   outsourceq ~    t acquisitionq ~ &t sacksq ~ t buildingq ~  t   secures $q ~ t india centerq ~    t introducingq ~ t mergingq ~ &t investsq ~ t makingq ~  t unveilq ~ t 
working onq ~  t    investingq ~ t intellectual propertyq ~ t 
takes overq ~ &t    partneredq ~ t 
innovationq ~ t m&aq ~ &t announceq ~ t offloadq ~     t iprq ~ t productivityq ~ t    innovatesq ~ t brings in $q ~ t joinedq ~ t launchedq ~ x`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess the person who gave you the file could give you an answer?

Comment: The person who is working earlier on this project is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file contain data which is generated by java serialization.
Java provides a mechanism, called object serialization where an object can be represented as a sequence of bytes that includes the object's data as well as information about the object's type and the types of data stored in the object.

After a serialized object has been written into a file, it can be read from the file and deserialized that is, the type information and bytes that represent the object and its data can be used to recreate the object in memory.

Most impressive is that the entire process is JVM independent, meaning an object can be serialized on one platform and deserialized on an entirely different platform.